# Generate PHP Documentation from NetBeans 6.8 project

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, phpdoc

Is there a way to generate PHPDoc documentation for a PHP project in Netbeans 6.8?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no direct support for PHPDoc in Netbeans. But here is an nice tutorial wich shows how to integrate it.

[Netbeans 6.5 with PHPDoc](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/generating_php_documentation_from_netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is - [PhpDocumentor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpdocu/)